# OpenCL only works as root

Tags: 14.10, opencl

No matter how I try to get OpenCL working (sgminer, cgminer, c programming examples, `clinfo`)

I only get a result when I run as root.

When I run `clinfo` not as root I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::Error'
what():  clGetPlatformIDs
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am using the AMD opencl implementation, and the correct ICD file does exist under /etc/OpenCL/vendors. I have changing the permissions of various files with no success.

How can I get this to work without root access

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I'm having a similar one, I would like to know if you could solve it.

Comment: @silgon, it was quite a while ago, and subsequently I stopped working on OpenCL - I don't recall if I got it working as non root.

Answer (score 4):

make sure that your user is added to the `video` group:

```
sudo adduser $USER video
```

Comment: This didn't help me. Still `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::Error'
  what():  clGetPlatformIDs
Aborted (core dumped)`

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps 9-11 of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20962333/1446892)

> 9. Optional: make symbolic links for desired system installed platforms: $     ln -s /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd /local/install/path/etc/vendors/nvidia.icd
> 10. export OPENCL_VENDOR_PATH=/local/install/path/etc/vendors
> 11. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/local/install/path/lib/x86_64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Doesn't work under Ubuntu 18.04.x. The same error message `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::Error'
  what():  clGetPlatformIDs
Aborted (core dumped)`.

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu 14.04

same errormessage. GPU not recognised.

symptom-no files in `/etc/OpenCL/vendors`

create files by

```
sudo gedit /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl64.icd
```

enter/paste `libamdocl64.so`

save

```
sudo gedit /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd
```

enter/paste `libamdocl32.so`

save

```
sudo gedit /etc/OpenCL/vendors/inteocl.icd
```

enter/paste `libintelocl.so`

save

```
sudo gedit /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd
```

enter/paste `libcuda.so`

save

This worked for me. I did a lot of other things also- symlinc and xhost- but they did not fix the problem finally.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.x. Your answer didn't help me, still `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::Error'
  what():  clGetPlatformIDs
Aborted (core dumped)
`